# Nothing happens when I try to use python to update excel

Tags: python, excel

After updating some of the details in the StringVar and IntVar variables, I'm trying to then have those values update the cells in the excel spreadsheet at the given row/index number. When I click to update, nothing happens.

```
path = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir="", title="Select A File")
wb = load_workbook(path)

sessions = pd.read_excel(path, sheet_name=2)
 
label = ttk.Label(billing_frame, text="Index Number")
label.grid(column=0, row=11, padx=2, pady=5)
browe = tk.IntVar()
row_entry = ttk.Entry(billing_frame, width=5, textvariable=browe)
row_entry.grid(column=0, row=12, padx=2, pady=5)

def sessionupdate():
    sessions.at[browe.get(),'Date'] == bdate1.get()
    sessions.at[browe.get(),'Provider'] == b_provider.get()
    sessions.at[browe.get(),'Position'] == b_position.get()
    sessions.at[browe.get(),'Client'] == b_client.get()
    sessions.at[browe.get(),'I/D'] == b_ID.get()
    sessions.at[browe.get(),'Start'] == btime.get()
    sessions.at[browe.get(),'Attendance'] == b_attend.get()
    sessions.at[browe.get(),'Insurance'] == binsurance.get()
    sessions.at[browe.get(),'OOP'] == bfee.get()
    sessions.at[browe.get(),'Code'] == b_code.get()
    sessions.at[browe.get(),'Insur Rate'] == bins.get()
    sessions.at[browe.get(),'Paid'] == bfeev.get()
    sessions.at[browe.get(),'iPaid'] == binsv.get()
    pd.sessions.to_excel(path)

update_button = ttk.Button(billing_frame, text="Update", command=sessionupdate)
update_button.grid(column=18, row=12)
```

Comment: I haven't done this with pandas before, but you surely need to actually save the file after making changes. That typically doesn't happen automatically. Also, those `==` look like they should be `=`? `==` is checking for equality, `=` is assignment.

Comment: Use [pandas.DataFrame.to_excel](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html)

Comment: @Xukrao do I put that at the beginning or end of the function?

Comment: At the end, after you have made all your modifications to the DataFrame object.

Comment: @Xukrao would that be before or after saving the file?

Comment: The `to_excel()` method saves an excel file.

Comment: @Xukrao I updated the code to reflect the changes and it returned, "module 'pandas' has no attribute 'sessions' "

Comment: `sessions` is a name that you created in your own script and only lives there. That's why you get an error message when you try to look for an attribute within the `pandas` module named `sessions`. The name `sessions` is linked to a `pd.DataFrame` object which contains the `to_excel()` attribute. Therefore you have to use `sessions.to_excel()`.

Comment: @Xukrao that wrote over the entire workbook. It also didn't apply the specific update I tried to make. Should I put the specific sheet name in the parentheses?

Comment: Values in your dataframe `sessions` don't get updated because you're using the wrong operator: you have to use `=` (assignment operator) instead of `==` (equality operator). The former assigns a value, the latter checks whether two values are equal.

Comment: As an example: what `sessions.at[browe.get(),'Date'] == bdate1.get()` does is generate a `True` or `False` value (that immediately gets lost, because it's not assigned to anything). On the other hand `sessions.at[browe.get(),'Date'] = bdate1.get()` will assign the value from `bdate1.get()` to `sessions.at[browe.get(),'Date']`, which I believe is what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When used alone, the function call `sessions.to_excel(path)` will always delete any existing workbook stored under `path` and replace it with a new one. Specifying a `sheet_name` parameter will not change this behaviour.

If you want to append a worksheet to an existing workbook, then you have to use the following code (replace "new_sheet" with your own worksheet name):

```
with pd.ExcelWriter(path, mode="a") as writer:
    sessions.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="new_sheet")
```

If you want to completely replace an existing worksheet in an existing workbook but leave the other worksheets intact, then you have to use the following code (replace "existing_sheet" with your own worksheet name):

```
with pd.ExcelWriter(path, mode="a", if_sheet_exists="replace") as writer:
    sessions.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="existing_sheet")
```

Finally if you want to overwrite the cells of an existing worksheet in an existing workbook without deleting the entire worksheet first, then you have to use the following code (replace "existing_sheet" with your own worksheet name):

```
with pd.ExcelWriter(path, mode="a", if_sheet_exists="overlay") as writer:
    sessions.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="existing_sheet")
```

For more information on parameters that you can use, see the documentation here:

- [`pandas.ExcelWriter`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.ExcelWriter.html)
- [`pandas.DataFrame.to_excel`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html)